# Understanding how to find the osculating plane for a helix.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm working through some practice items and am attempting to understand the steps involved in computing the osculating plane for a helix.  Consider the given helix to be $r(t) = \langle\sin(2t), \cos(2t), -t\rangle$.

I realize we must first compute the binormal vector, and arrive at

[image: Binomial Vector Link]

Afterwards, I know the final equation but am totally lost on how to arrive there.  Please help!

Comment: How do you give the equation of a plane?